# .map_diag(plt.hist,bins=30) - no histograms on diagonal line

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-visualization

I wanted to use seaborn and pandas to make some visualizations of my data. I used this code:

```
returns_fig = sns.PairGrid(tech_rets.dropna())

returns_fig.map_upper(plt.scatter,color='purple')

returns_fig.map_lower(sns.kdeplot,cmap='cool_d')

returns_fig.map_diag(plt.hist,bins=30)
```

It works almost perfectly but I do not get histograms on the diagonal line.

Note: I use Google Colab.

What do I have to change here?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `returns_fig.map_diag(sns.histplot,bins=30)`?

Comment: This works :-) But I meant plt.hist. But your solution should be fine as well. Thanks!

Comment: Seaborn works on top of matplotlib and uses its functions. Usually, a combination will be fine in Seaborn because Seaborn changes minor aspects [(see for instance here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65393950/8881141). In a higher-order plot like PairGrid where Seaborn organizes the display of three different types of graphs and coordinates their display over axes objects. In this case, I would only use Seaborn functionality to be on the safe side (e.g., `plt.scatter()` is also suboptimal).