# Python - Use bins from one sns.histplot() for another / Extract bin information from an sns.histplot()

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram, bins

I am trying to plot 2 histograms side by side, the first one for the full dataset, and second one for a subset of the dataset. For comparability, I want both to have the same class intervals and the bin widths must be calculated as per the Freedman-Diaconis rule, (probably the default mode used by sns.histplot as per a stackoverflow answer).

I want the first histogram's bins to be the defaults decided by the sns.histplot() function.
Then I want to extract the list of bin intervals or break points used by the first plot, and use that as an argument while generating the second histogram.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston = load_boston()
df = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)

# Histograms
f, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 4.5))
a = sns.histplot(df['NOX'], ax=axs[0], color='steelblue')
b = sns.histplot(df.NOX[df.CRIM > 10.73], ax=axs[1], color='darkgreen')
plt.show()
```

**Questions:**
**1) How to extract the list of bins used by a sns.histplot()**
**2) How to plot 2 histograms with same bins, using the Freedman-Diaconis rule?**

Comment: I don't think you can extract the bins from a [seaborn histplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65393950/8881141) easily but I might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC . Your suggestion worked. If you would post it as an answer, I would upvote it.

Comment: @JohanC, I'm also looking for a way to annotate the bars of both histograms with values and or %. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seaborn usually doesn't give access to its calculations, it just tries to create visualizations. But you can use the same underlying functions to get its results. You need [`bins = np.histogram_bin_edges(..., bins='auto')`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.histogram_bin_edges.html) (or `bins='fd'` to force the Freedman Diaconis Estimator). And then `sns.histplot(..., bins=bins)` for both.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

boston = load_boston()
df = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)

bins = np.histogram_bin_edges(df['NOX'], bins='auto')
f, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 4.5))
sns.histplot(df['NOX'], bins=bins, color='steelblue', ax=axs[0])
sns.histplot(df[df['CRIM'] > 10.73]['NOX'], bins=bins, color='darkgreen', ax=axs[1])
for ax in axs:
    for p in ax.patches:
        x, w, h = p.get_x(), p.get_width(), p.get_height()
        if h > 0:
            ax.text(x + w / 2, h, f'{h / len(df) * 100:.2f}%\n', ha='center', va='center', size=8)
    ax.margins(y=0.07)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: I am trying to label both histograms in a loop. I have figured out how to label them individually with `for p in fig1.patches: ... `, but not how to do this for both figures in a loop.